# Is there a way to avoid Hibernate to search for a column?

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following class:

Film.java

```
public class Film implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String fbId;

    ...

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="genre", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="film"))
    private Collection<String> genres;

}
```

"genre" is just a table, there's no class implementing it. In my DB it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE genre(
    film VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES film(id),
    genre VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (film,genre)
);
```

When I test the project I get the following error:

> Missing column: genres in DB_FILMS.PUBLIC.GENRE

Of course there's no "genres" column, the collection is just a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the @Column

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="genre", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="film"))
@Column(name="genre")
private Collection<String> genres;
```